# File permission issue after updating Laravel Homestead box

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead, parallels

I updated my Laravel Homestead box to version 13.0.0 and I now have a file permission issue :

> The stream or file "/home/vagrant/code/Test/back/storage/logs/laravel-2023-06-21.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied

Here are my permissions on the storage directory :

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant     256 Jun 21 02:20 storage
```

I tried to chown to www-data:www-data, as I read about that on other tickets, but it does not work.
It even does not work when setting chmod to 777...

This was working fine before updating my box. I have reloaded the box, restarted my Mac without more success.

Config :

- Vagrant 2.3.7
- Homestead box 14.2.0 (Settler 13.0.0)
- Parallels for Mac 18.3.1
- Mac OS Ventura 13.4 (ARM)

Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, no idea what happened but after running `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` it works.